# Is it possible to chain together PHP require?

Tags: php, include, require

What I'm looking to do is to set up a dev subdomain of my site.

The structure is essentially this:

```
/vitals.php <-- Contains the actual info (passwords, db info, etc...)
/public_html/vitals.php <-- contains only require("../vitals.php")
/public_html/index.php
/public_html/dev/index.php
```

The index file in public_html has `require("../vitals.php")`.  I want to be able to use the same line in the `dev/index.php` file by adding the extra vitals.php in public html which would in turn include the `vital.php` outside of public_html.

The problem is...it doesn't work.  Ideas?

Comment: Did you try `require("../../vitals.php")`? Your question is a bit vague and hard to understand, please clarify.

Comment: I advise you to define in a root file a constant representing the root path of your application (example: `define('APPLICATION_PATH', __DIR__`), and then, use it in all your include or requiered in order to give absolute path. because, with your method, you are playing with relative path and you could be confused. Take a look at : http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: "it doesn't work" isn't an explanation

Comment: Include relative to `__DIR__`, `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, or some other `define()`'d directory.

Comment: Sorry, I know that it isn't very clear but I'm just not sure how to re-word it.  I'm just trying to make an exact copy of the site inside of another folder.  I don't want to have to change the require statements on the dev subdomain.

When I say it doesn't work, the dev subdomain only includes `vitals.php` in the public_html folder (which contains only another require statement) and not the desired `vitals.php` in the doc root.

Answer (score 1):

The active directory doesn't change just because you're including a file. Personally, I like to start my code with `chdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])`, as this will allow me to include files identically no matter what folder I'm in.

Answer (score 0):

You are having problem with the relative path of the require.  Just use an absolute path and the require will work regardless of whether it is in you dev subdirectory or not.

i.e.

```
require('/path/to/vitals.php');
```

Comment: I could do this but I'm trying to keep from having to rewrite the require statements for the pages that are going to be in the dev folder as a subdomain.

Comment: If they are in a subdomain, just put the entire folder in it's own directory structure defined for that virtual host rather than nesting in another virtual host's directory, you are just causing yourself unnecessary problems.

Answer (score 0):

`require`, `include`, and friends, look in the current [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) first, and then in the directory of the script file. The working directory will initially be the directory of the visited page. It won't be different in the included file, so it will simply try to include the same file again, and not manage to get up the tree.

A better way might be to just jump directly to the root:

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/vitals.php';
```